# Get Android Paging 3.0 with RxJava working in Java (not Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, paging

I managed to get Paging library 3.0.0-alpha02 working with RxJava2 in a Kotlin app, following the Paging 3 [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#java).

However I had a problem when I ported the paging code to a Java app, in that the data is being retrieved by page, but the page retrieval keeps happening in the background even when I don't scroll the recyclerview. In other words, after loading page 1, it then loads page 2, 3, 4, etc, and keeps going.

I'm setting up the paging in the viewmodel:

```
public Observable<PagingData<Item>> loadItems()
{

  PagingConfig config = new PagingConfig(...);

  Pager<Integer, Message> pager = new Pager<Integer, Item>(config, null, null,
                                        () -> new MyPagingSource());

  return PagingRx.getObservable(pager) 
}
```

Then subscribe in the activity/fragment:

```
        disposable = viewModel.loadItems()
            .subscribe( pagingData -> {
            getAdapter().submitData(getLifecycle(), pagingData);
        });
```

In the Java app, I'm subscribing in a fragment instead of and an activity, but otherwise the code is the same as the Kotlin app.

I realize that the paging library 3 uses coroutines and flow internally, so I added this dependency but it didn't make any difference.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:1.3.7'
```

**Edit:**

The Kotlin demo app is on [GitHub](https://github.com/davidwong/Paging3-ContentProvider) and has a RxJava as well as a Flow version (based on the Android samples). It does paging on the Telephony content provider to get SMS inbox messages.

Answer (score 1):

`PagingSource.load` is automatically triggered based on `PagingConfig.prefetchDistance` as items are bound to `RecyclerView`. This means that even if you don't scroll, Paging will try to fulfill items based on visible viewport.

Terminating load behaves the same regardless of what language you're using, but it is based on `prev/nextKey` being `null` for `LoadResult.Page` in `PagingSource` and `endOfPaginationReached` in `RemoteMediator`.

If you believe that this is an issue with the library, I'd encourage you to file an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106&template=1096385 with an attached repro, and I'd be happy to take a look!

Otherwise if you could attach your `PagingSource` implementation, that would help as there isn't much information to go on with what you've posted so far.

Comment: The PagingSource seems to be working ok, I added a link to the Kotlin code in the question and the source is in app/src/main/java/au/com/dw/paging3contentprovider/rx/MessageRxPageSource.kt. The Java version is just a port and is in a gist: https://gist.github.com/davidwong/4196b1c92d20e479eda56f0445683b61.

Comment: In the java variant you are passing 0 for itemsBefore and itemsAfter, but using the default, COUNT_UNDEFINED in kotlin when constructing LoadResult.Page.

Comment: I tried changed those parameters to LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED, but still not working. Appreciate your answers, but I leave this until paging 3 is passed alpha stage to try again. Or until I can find some working examples of paging 3 in java.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Paging 3.0 with RxJava does work properly, when it is being used in an activity. I have the problem because I had the recyclerview, adapter, etc in a fragment. Not sure why this is, possibly due to differences in the lifecycle?